# py2exe can not find target script

Tags: python, py2exe

Here's my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    console = [{'script': "target.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

target.py is in the same directory as setup.py, when I run the command (have to use full path or it doesn't even get this response):

```
C:\Python\app\python.exe C:\Final\setup.py py2exe
```

the response in command is:

```
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
error: target.py: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and it's probably quite dumb. If anyone has any idea I'd appreciate the input.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just change Your current working directory to `C:\Final\` using `cd` command and run:
`C:\Python\app\python.exe setup.py py2exe`